# Which will be executed first, RAII or function return value

Tags: c++, multithreading

`MyClass` has a member function that needs to return its' member variable, and
the function must be thread safe, so I use a mutex to protect the data.

I have two implementation as below:

version 1:

```
string MyClass::name() {
    m_mutex.lock();
    string temp = m_name;
    m_mutex.unlock();
    return temp;
}
```

version 2:

```
string MyClass::name() {
    MutexLocker lock(mutex);
    return m_name;
}
```

I known that version 1 has no problem, but I need to type more code.

The problem is, I'm not sure whether version 2 is correct or not. Will the mutex lock will be released before the thread access `m_name`?

Comment: Now that you know that version 2 is correct and safe, I can then argue that version 1 is potentially unsafe, as with any operation that isn't protected with an RAII wrapper in the presence of possible exceptions (and negligence to release the resource). Not only does the RAII version take less effort to type, it also makes your code very safe. That's what I call a win-win!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The version 2 is correct as well (in fact, that is *better* than the first version!).

The value is copied first before mutex is released through the destructor of the local object. The opposite is not possible because the local object gets destroyed when it goes out of scope, but you must note that the return statement must be executed in the scope, so it must happen before destruction. Conversely, the return statement cannot be executed after the local object goes out of scope.

From call-stack point of view, the  local objects are destroyed when the stack starts unwinding, but the function including the return statement is executed long before stack-unwinding. That ensures `m_name` is copied much before the releasing the mutex.

Or think of this simple code:

```
std::string f()
{
    std::string s = "Nawaz";
    return s; //Think of this line!
}
```

Is `s` copied<sup>1</sup> *after* its destruction? Is that even possible? Wouldn't it make programming in C++ impossible if `s` is copied *after* its destruction?

<sup>1. Or better say, *moved*. :-)</sup>

Comment: Glad to know that RAII doesn't fail on this seemingly edge case scenario.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: It's not edge case at all. If it was different, it would fail on returning any complex local variable, ever.

Comment: I would actually make the case that version 2 is not only fine, but is actually the safer approach.  If an exception is thrown between the lock and unlock, the mutex would never unlock.

Comment: `Is s copied after its destruction?` On some cases it won't be copied or destroyed at all (well, actually later destroyed but not in `f()`). `;)`